# Reading each line from a text file for a banned word list

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

So, I've been trying to create a banned word list for a bot I'm creating for Discord, I've been running into trouble of it not working at all.

Here is the code I've tried.

```
public static string fileName1 = "banned_words.txt";
if (e.Message.RawText.Contains(File.ReadLines(fileName1).ToString()))
  {
    e.Message.Delete();
    Console.WriteLine(e.User.Name + " said " + e.Message.RawText.Clone());
    e.Channel.SendMessage(e.User.Mention + " Please do not use that language!");
  }
```

Comment: How does it *not work*? Does it throw an exception or just doesn't print the message?

Comment: How the contents of the file are aligned? is that single lined with space separated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking if the message coming in contains the entire banned_words list as an `IEnumerable` of strings converted to a string which is probably the literal value "``` IEnumerable``String ```" or similar representation.

You should instead look through each string in the banned_words.txt file one at a time, and check if the message contains them one at a time:

```
foreach (string badWord in File.ReadLines(fileName1)) {
    if (e.Message.RawText.Contains(badWord)) {
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I should've done this, is there a way to ignore case sensitive?

Comment: Yes, you can specify a different string comparison: `if (e.Message.RawText.Contains(badWord, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) {`

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to what Tim said, you can make it case insensitive by simply comparing two uppercase words, e.g.

```
foreach (string badWord in File.ReadLines(fileName1)) {
if (e.Message.RawText.ToUpper().Contains(badWord.ToUpper())) {
    //Do stuff
}
```